# GStreamer Recording and Viewing Stream Simultaneously

Tags: gstreamer

I have a strange task at hand, and I've tried everything. I was wondering if you could help.

My task is to grab a stream put out by a RaspPi and save it to my PC. However, I need to view AND save it simultaneously.

This works to view it:

gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=false

Okay, great. Now to save it simultaneously.

I am just not experienced enough to figure this out. I know I have to use the "tee" command. But that's all I know...

Help?

Comment: Ask this on **superuser.com**.

Comment: gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! t. tee name=t ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=false t. ! filesink location=video

Comment: @karlphillip no this is perfect for stackoverflow ;) gst-launch is script like language .. just check some gstreamer questions - they usually use gst-launch for demonstration..

Answer (score 4):

Here's a test pipeline that renders **videotestsrc**, encodes it, and then saves it to disk:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vv videotestsrc ! tee name=t ! queue leaky=1 ! autovideosink sync=false t. ! queue ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=testvideo.mp4
```

As explained here:

http://www.oz9aec.net/index.php/gstreamer/410-x264enc-problem-in-gstreamer-video-switcher-solved

that pipeline has two branches with wildly different rates of processing, so that's why you need to set a **leaky** queue in the rendering branch (and also disable clock synchronization). Otherwise, this example pipeline blocks.

In your question you don't explain what format you want to save, but probably you want to save it encoded. I suggest that you use `gst-inspect-1.0` and read the specs for each filter carefully, so you know what type of buffes are flowing through each plugin. This will help you find the proper plugins you need to connect to encode and save the stream.

Gstreamer can be confusing at times, but I really suggest that you look around a bit longer next time. The gstreamer-devel mailing list is a good source of information: http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/