# Tee element stops pipeline in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to create a pipeline which reads a file from a path and
a) encodes the video with h264 and stores the result in **avi** format
b) opens an **autovideosink** and shows the video

this is the code im trying to run:

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v  filesrc location=sample.mp4 ! decodebin ! tee name=t ! queue ! x264enc  !  avimux ! filesink  location=myVid.avi   t. ! queue !  autovideosink
```

which ends in an empty output.
I tried individual parts and they work correctly:

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=sample.mp4 ! decodebin ! x264enc ! avimux ! filesink location=myVid.avi
```

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v  filesrc location=sample.mp4 ! decodebin  ! autovideosink
```

but when I try **"tee"** it dosnt work.

Comment: One approach is to use `queue leaky=1 ! autovideosink sync=false` from [GStreamer Recording and Viewing Stream Simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37461160/704244)

Comment: Another approach is to increase queue buffer size `queue max-size-bytes=20485760 max-size-time=0 ! autovideosink` and the video will be played at normal speed

Comment: It looks like there is a delay at the beginning of encoding and a large buffer has enough capacity to initiate the process.